# custom Envelope EmailBlurb message text in better format like in Word document

Tags: docusignapi

How to create envelope with custom Envelope EmailBlurb message text in a prettier format like Word document or HTML?  How to achieve this, using HTML text in EmailBlurb or other DocuSign attributes & setting to enable rich format of EmailBlurb?

Thanks in advance,
CT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EmailBlurb does support a limited set of HTML formatting. I can confirm that things like bold, italics and hyperlinks all function.

If your HTML isn't being processed and is instead coming through raw (ex: `"hello <b>signer</b>"` instead of "hello **signer**" please open [a Support Case](https://support.docusign.com/en/createCase) requesting *Allow HTML input in the API* be enabled for your account. If this is for a Demo account, specify that and include the account ID.

Comment: Thank you, Drew.  Good to know this flexibility and how to enable it.  In our case, the generic Email Message body could applies to all envelope and shown in different DocuSign email templates.  So, the modifying the Email Profile file might be the better option.   Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [the DocuSign Email Resources File](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1) for this.

[image]

These are HTML based.

Comment: Hin Inbar, thanks for the helpful information.  How to tell which Email Template

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for the helpful information.  There are 298 Email Templates message body. How to tell one to use? Which one is the default email template when I sent Envelope using tempalte to a recipient from the DocuSign admin site?

I added additional HTML text to  the first one "ChangeSigner_HtmlBody" and upload the Email resource file to Demo DocuSign. But when I create the Envelope and send to myself, it's not showing the additional text.

Thank you,
CT

Comment: Hi Inbar, to clarify, the Envelope will be created using Server-templates by calling one of DocuSign SOAP create envelope operation. I was looking at incorrect Email template. It should be the "Agent Notification" email template - "AgentNotification_HtmlBody". correct?

I apologize for any confusion.  I wasn't clear of what "Manage Envelope recipient" means. 

Thank you,
CT

Comment: Those templates are account level, and applied to all envelopes regardless if sent via template or not. The specific terms and things to change are described in the document, I don't know exactly what has to be changed, sometimes it requires some tinkering...